# socket.io connection doesn't work, xhr poll error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, socket.io

I tried cloning the chat example in socket.io tutorial and it just wouldn't work. 
Then I installed firecamp and found out that socket.io is at fault.
I typed socket.firecamp.io in the address bar and I got the following error:
Error: xrh poll error
How can I fix it?
Here's the code:

```
//Connection
const socket = io( "socket.firecamp.io", {
  "transports": ["polling","websocket"]
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  console.log("socket disconnected");
});

// for more information: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md
```

Comment: `socket.firecamp.io` domain no longer exists. please try another live socket server's ep.

Comment: have you found the solution to this?

Comment: I forgot I posted it, it was a while ago.